# Manage Success and Error responses from services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

On my controller I have a huge number of calls to services, so each time that I'm getting a response I'm doing the same operation, so I would like to know if there's is a way to unify the "success" and "error" functionalities for each service call in order to remove, repeated code,

also, If there's a way where should be placed?

```
 this.UpdateProfile = function (profile) {

                profilePageDataService.UpdateProfile(profile)
                    .success(
                        function (data, status) {
                          alert('Yeah');                                    
                        })
                    .error(
                        function (data, status) {                          
                           alert('Ko');    
                        });
     };
```

**EDIT:**

So, I would like to clarify that, I would like to take out only the "success and error ", because the code  inside is the same,

```
this.UpdateProfileName = function (profile) {

                profilePageDataService.UpdateProfileName(profile)
                    .success(
                        function (data, status) {        
                           alert('Yeah');              
                        })
                    .error(
                        function (data, status) {                          
                            alert('Ko'); 
                        });
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback to the service function.

```
this.UpdateProfile = function (profile, callback) {

    var cb = callback || angular.noop; // just a safer way. do nothing in you did not specify `callback` variable.

    profilePageDataService.UpdateProfile(profile)
        .success(
            function (data, status) {
                return cb(data);
        })
        .error(
            function (data, status) {                          
                return cb(data);
        });
};
```

And to get the callback:

```
var userProfile = {};

MyService.UpdateProfile(userProfile, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about moving your `UpdateProfile` function in **$rootScope**:

```
angular.module('scopeExample', [])
.controller('RootController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', 'profilePageDataService', function($scope, $rootScope, profilePageDataService) {

  $rootScope.UpdateProfile = function (profile) {

                profilePageDataService.UpdateProfile(profile)
                    .success(
                        function (data, status) {

                          //Some operations here...

                        })
                    .error(
                        function (data, status) {                          
                          //.....
                        });
     };
}])
.controller('ProfileController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   //UpdateProfile function moved from here to $rootScope
}]);
```

I think the above could work (note I haven't tested it), but the above code was implemented following [Angular's Scope Hierarchies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) sample.

There's another alternative that might work in this case too, and it involves using [AngularUI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).